# Порядок инициализации DependencyProperty и Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Имеется `UserControl` который содержит в себе `ComboBox`. В code-behind заполняются значения и задается `ComboBox->SelectedValue` через привязанное свойство `SelectedValueLocal`. Сеттер свойства `SelectedValueLocal` также устанавливает значение для `DependencyProperty SelectedValue`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMVVM.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMVVM"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValueLocal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>     
</UserControl>
```

code-behind

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /*реализация INPC*/

    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    string _selectedValueLocal;
    public string SelectedValueLocal
    {
        get { return _selectedValueLocal; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedValueLocal = value;
            SelectedValue = _selectedValueLocal; //передача в DP
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Values = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

        SelectedValueLocal = Values.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Использование UserControl:

```
<StackPanel>           
    <local:UserControl1 SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>     
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedText}"/> <!--ожидаю "one"-->
</StackPanel>
```

При запуске приложения я ожидаю в SelectedText выбранное значение у ComboBox, но привязка начинает работать только после выбора элемента в ComboBox. Я подозреваю что когда задается начальное значение DependencyProperty в code-behing, оно в это время не привязано ни к чему и соответственно значение не доходит до адресата. Есть ли способ заставить обновить привязку после запуска приложения программно?

Comment: Подозреваю что привязка односторонняя, попробуйте задать явно `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: А почему у вас `SelectedValue` — это нормальное DependencyProperty, а `SelectedValueLocal` — просто свойство с INPC? Это вполне может запутать WPF.

Comment: @aepot, хотелось бы так, но мне нужна привязка OneWayToSource. т.е. только получать значение от контрола

Comment: @SelectedValueLocal ис-ся для внутренней логики контрола, SelectedValue - для связи с внешним миром. Вообще в реальном коде у них еще и разный тип)

Answer (score 3):

Строка `SelectedValue = _selectedValueLocal` в сеттере `SelectedValueLocal` затирает `Binding` свойства `SelectedValue`, заменяя его на непосредственное значение.

Попробуйте использовать вместо этого [`SetCurrentValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Попробовал, к сожалению ничего не изменилось. Но благодаря этим действия, я заметил что и в том и в другом случае при инициализации, в сеттер SelectedText в VM поступает null.

Comment: а когда начинает работу Binding? После выполнения конструктора UserControl или после?

Comment: @Gardes: Ну в порядке выполенения. Код `<local:UserControl1 SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>` транслируется в такой: `UserControl1 x = new UserControl1(); x.SetBinding(UserControl1.SelectedValue, new Binding("SelectedText", ...); stackPanel.Children.Add(x);`.

Comment: Интерпретация XAML происходит внутри вызова `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: в таком случае, начальное значение установленное в конструкторе не будет обновлено в биндинге, хм

Answer (score 1):

> Я подозреваю что когда задается начальное значение DependencyProperty в code-behing, оно в это время не привязано ни к чему и соответственно значение не доходит до адресата. Есть ли способ заставить обновить привязку после запуска приложения программно?

Привязки настраиваются после работы конструктора. Так, задать значение по умолчанию и быть уверенным что оно дойдет до viewmodel необходимо задавать после настройки привязки, а именно через событие `Loaded`:

```
public UserControl1()
{         
    InitializeComponent();

    Values = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

    this.Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;           
}

private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetCurrentValue(SelectedValueProperty, Values.FirstOrDefault());
}
```